# NPV calculation using monte carlo simulation

Tags: modeling

I need help in solving part b). I need to solve it using excel can someone help?

> a) Conduct a discounted cash flow calculation to determine the NPV of the following project, assuming a required rate of return of 0.22. The project will cost 75,000 USD but will result in cash inflows of 18,000 USD, 25,000 USD, 35,000 USD, and 50,000 USD in each of the next four years.
>
> b) In Problem a), assume that the inflows are uncertain but normally distributed with standard deviations of 1000 USD, 1500 USD, 2000 USD, and 3000 USD, respectively. Find the mean forecast NPV. What is the probability the actual NPV will be positive? Hint: Use Monte Carlo simulation

I solved part a) using this:
$$\text{NPV} = 75000 + \frac{18000}{1+0.22} + \frac{25000}{(1 + 0.22)^2} + \frac{35000}{(1 + 0.22)^3}  + \frac{50000}{(1+ 0.22)^4}$$
However, in part b) the inflows are not constant and have a normal distribution. How can I calculate the NPV in such cases? Can someone tell me how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to SE.OR! We welcome anything related to operations research, like your problem, however, we cannot solve your homework questions. Please tell us, what you already tried, what you expected and what not worked.

Comment: I have solved part a) using the formula for Net Present Value. How should I approach part b.) I just need some hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried using Monte Carlo simulation as given by the hint? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is a homework problem to be solved and nothing will be added to the community by answering this question.

Comment: @Oguz Toragay I believe homework questions are acceptable if the asker details their process and asks a specific question. Also see the [meta discussion](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/should-we-allow-questions-about-homework-problems).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt to solve the problem using Monte Carlo simulation. I used [Palisade software package](https://www.palisade.com/)

Monte Carlo solution to the problem: I simulated the problem using 10,000 iterations.
[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OxRZ.png

Comment: Thanks, I'm relative new here just getting used to the site.

Comment: And we are all here in this community to help. You can find a lot of useful information on [Meta](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/) about what type of questions you might ask yourself, formatting, and a lot more.